# The diminishing role of the "family name" throughout the Byzantine Empire

Tags: cultural-history, byzantine-empire, surname

Why did the use of the **family name** ([Cognomen](http://www.behindthename.com/glossary/view/cognomen)), as one's **surname**, diminish and nearly disappear entirely during the 4th - 11th centuries throughout the Eastern Roman Empire?

[Brief history](http://www.unrv.com/culture/roman-naming-practices.php) of the early existing Roman naming practices of the Principate Period (27 BC – 284 AD)

---

> According to Christopher Andersen (1977), the ancient Greeks, Hebrews,
>   and **Romans** had surnames. After the fall of the Roman Empire,
>   however, surnames [disappeared until the eleventh century](http://family.jrank.org/pages/1196/Names-Children-Surnames.html).

**NOTE:** In the text above, Christopher Andersen was strictly referring to the ***Roman Empire*** which would have been a predecessor to the **Byzantine Empire** (Eastern Roman Empire | 330 AD to 1453 AD).

Comment: Good question. I'm unfamilar with this phenomenon though, so it would have been nice if you'd linked a reference of some kind in the question.

Comment: @TED I have updated my question to include links and some extra information.

Comment: @TED Did the updates to the question help?

Comment: Yes. However, I don't see anything in either link specifically about the Byzantine Empire. It would make sense to me that this might happen in *Europe* during the Dark Ages, just due to the general impoverishment of the culture. If it also occurred in relatively well-off Byzantium, that would be different though.

Comment: @TED As noted in my updated question the time period in which this ended was at the end of the Roman Empire which would be the beginning of the Byzantine Empire. And the return of surnames came about in the 11th century in the time of the Byzantine Empire. I actually think I may have found what I was looking for here: http://heraldry.sca.org/laurel/names/byzantine/introduction.html If you would like to take a look I will give you the credit :–)

Comment: Heh. No, if you find the answer yourself, you might as well answer the question with it (even if you asked the question in the first place). As long as you don't make a habit of that to farm rep, I don't think anyone here will mind.

Comment: @TED I would like to read a bit further and maybe find some references with this site. But it does look promising.

Comment: I know it is really a matter of convention, but counting the beginning of Eastern Roman Empire from 476 makes no sense.

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic Yeah I see your point. I believe the actual end of the Western Roman Empire was 476 AD perhaps I should change the date to 330 AD to match the founding of Constantinople. Thank you for kindly bringing this to my attention. I wonder why no one else had commented on this?

Comment: @E1Suave: Eh, never mind - as I said it is really a matter of convention. Strictly speaking, there was no separate "Eastern" and "Western" Empire before 800 AD, but (some) historians like to make a break between "classical" Rome and "Byzantine Empire" so they pick various dates for that purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that the diminshing use of the Roman *three-name practice* (which includes the cognomen as the 3rd name) was primarily due to the influence of early Christian & Greek "naming" traditions.

---

> [Personal Names of the Aristocracy in the Roman Empire During the Later Byzantine Era](http://heraldry.sca.org/laurel/names/byzantine/introduction.html)
>   ...
>
> Personal names in the Byzantine era of the Roman Empire consisted of a 
>   given name followed by one or more surnames. Surnames came in three 
>   varieties: inherited **family names**, patronymics, and by-names.
>
> ...
>
> As Christianity became the dominant (and eventually state) religion, it
>   became popular to use the names of saints *instead of the three name
>   practice*.
>
> ...
>
> The cognomen (or family name) had begun to disappear as well. With
>    the infusion of [Greek culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_name#Greek_surnames) into the Roman Empire, the use of
>   patronymics ('son of') and by-names (both attributive, such as 'the wise' 
>   or 'the short', and descriptive, such as 'of Antioch' or 'the tailor') began 
>   to displace inherited surnames. The Greeks did not have as keenly
>   developed a sense of genealogy as did the Romans. The Byzantine era
>   being a blending of the two, the value of hereditary family names
>   declined, and so did their use. Family names are completely missing or
>   extremely rare in documents and seals dated from between the 7th and
>   10th centuries. Eventually, family names were seen as a quaint custom.

**Additional information:**

- [Cognomen](http://www.gottschalg.com/genealogy/german/english/oursurnameswhattheyrevealandconceal/index.php)
- [Early Christian and Greek traditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_name#Given_names)

Comment: @TED I was fortunate in finding the article above. In many ways I stumbled across it while attempting to help add clarification to my question. So special thanks to TED. :–)